# Override footer/header section

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I was trying to modify footer section with outlets by defining:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="templateName$ | async">
        <ng-template *ngIf="true" cxOutletRef="footer">
        </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

and footer section is not replaced. Is it possible to replace footer/header for specific templates?
As a result of this code, templateName is properly resolved from PageLayoutService, but it replacing does not work.
Also tried

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(templateName$ | async) === expectedTemplateName">
        <ng-template cxOutletRef="footer">
        </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

but still no luck.
Any hints? It would be great to modify/change header as well, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to customise the header/footer of a page:

- Implement the customisation in the CMS, where you can setup different page templates for different pages, including an alternative header/footer. This approach would align best with how Spartacus is build, as the pages are data driven and component mapping is done in a generic way. You don't need to touch the spartacus code to get different headers and footers.
- Use outlets as you tried already. The issue you're facing is that at the time that the page template is resolved, the footer is already rendered and the registered outlet will not make a difference. I can imagine this is a bit confusing in how outlets work. I've created a quick example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/spartacus-conditional-outlet-footer) for a conditional footer using outlets.
- Implement a custom root component (replacing `cx-storefront`) and implement the footer in a custom way. You can leverage the page-layout and page-slot component to render CMS content.

Hope that gives you and idea or two.

---

Here's a bit more info on page template driven classes for page specific styling. Given that the header/footer do not benefit from the page template based class (as it's only available inside the router outlet), you could implement this in your app, I've updated the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/spartacus-conditional-outlet-footer) example for you with an example.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! My preference would be to go with 1st solution as in my opinion it seems to be the most simple and the amount of implementation is low.

Comment: I have prepared a proper CMS structure and slots/components are displayed properly. The problem that I am currently struggling with is that I do not know how can I apply particular styles to a section (footer/header) to a specific template only. Is it possible in Spartacus?

Comment: There's indeed no out of the box way to get a notion of the page template inside the header/footer. This is only available when the page is rendered inside the router outlet.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example on how to do this.

Comment: The solution we have chosen is the 1st and 3rd bullet points combined. Works great